# How to programmatically close an HTML5 form validation error message?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, validation

How to programmatically close an HTML5 form validation error message?

After a form validation error message pops up, how do I programmatically close or hide it?

I'm using Opera 11.51.

Comment: What's a "form validation error message"? Do you mean an `alert` box?

Comment: @Xeon06, try this http://www.diveintohtml5.org/examples/input-required.html in the latest versions of Opera, Chrome, Firefox, etc. An error message should appear. I want to programmatically close the error message.

Comment: Oh snap. That's a great question. I'd add that info to the main post.

Comment: do you have the code that shows that error message? If you did we could show you how to clear it.

Comment: There is no 'code that shows that error' and furthermore if you look in FireBug there is no HTML added to the DOM to display this message. Are we to believe it is akin to an Alert? How is this object then managed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the input field is invalid in HTML5, it sets an "invalid" attribute on the element.  To hide it, I believe you can capture this event and then return `false` to set it back to valid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- // suppress "invalid" event
$('#element').bind('invalid', function() {
   return false;
});
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, but I want the error message to show at first, and then after a period of time or after an event, I want to programmatically close the error message.

Comment: I've been playing around with how to set the validity of the element programatically, but I can't find a good answer.

It's a bit of a hack, but the error message goes away when you lose focus so you could just `blur` the element and then send focus back to it.

Comment: `inputElement.blur(); inputElement.focus();` works. I'll accept this until we discover a better way.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is quite vague but i think you mean something like, being able to clear error messages you give your user right?

If you're making the error message appear in a div box you specified, just use an `onClick` function to clear the message from that div. something like this.

```
document.onMousedown=function(ev){
document.getElementById('THE DIV WITH THE ERROR MESSAGE').innerHTML = null;

}
```

Comment: No, I'm talking about HTML5 client-side form validation error messages. See http://www.diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#validation and comment above in the OP.